# Hybris core itemtypes

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

sorry if it is too simple questions. I am using b2c extension and cannot find definition of `Product and Category itemtypes` definition. Can someone direct me where to search that files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of an item can be done through several files in hybris.

In the case of product, depending of the extensions you use, your model will change.
To know all files that define product use your IDE research and look for all `itemtype code="Product"` in all `*.items.xml`.

In the case of catalog you can do the same thing, currently all the definition is done in one file : catalog-items.xml in platform/ext/catalog/resources

An other way to know all attributes defined for a type is to use the backoffice.

Go to system->types and search for your type, then in property tab you will find the list of all attributes defined for this type.

Answer (score 0):

product and category should be there in core item xml file present in platform .

One needs to extend it in custom extension and define in custom item xml .